# Getting error in selenium web driver in Ubuntu

Tags: maven, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver

**Note : Program is working fine in Window Os. Getting issue only in Ubuntu Os.**

Selenium Webdriver: 2.40

FF Version: 27.0

Using Maven plugin.

I tried to run the Selenium webdriver automation scripts in Ubuntu machine.

I have got the following error.  Please help me to solve this issue.

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect
>   to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
>
> (process:8689): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion
>   'sys_page_size == 0' failed Error: cannot open display: 1.0
>
> (process:8697): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion
>   'sys_page_size == 0' failed Error: cannot open display: 1.0
>
> at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:112)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:192)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:187)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:183)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:100)

Comment: are u running headless???

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use selenium latest version 2.44.0. Download latest version [From Here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

Selenium latest version supports till firefox version 33.

Comment: Hi..thanks for the update. But Selenium webdriver 2.40 supports FF 27.0. Also it is working fine in Windows. In Ubuntu machine only, i'm facing this issue. Any configuration changes required in Ubuntu machine?

Comment: Have you added all JARs to your project in eclipse?

Comment: Yes..i run the scripts using maven. It downloads all required jars into my project.

Comment: you should clarify these all things in question that you are using maven , program runs proper in windows. Issue with only ubuntu etc...